# How can I change the Framework path my Python file is referring?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, monterey, python

I'm trying to run a 3rd-party application with Python. I understand that Monterey has done away with the system-installed Python 2.7, however, this application was released before Monterey. When I try to run it, I get:

```
python: posix_spawn:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python:
No such file or directory
```

The programming for the application is looking for the framework file in `/System/Library/Frameworks`. However, since Monterey got rid of the system installed Python, Python.framework does not exist in `System/Library/Framework`. I had to download it on my own, and because of that the framework file only appears in `Library/Frameworks`.

How can I change the path that Terminal runs when trying to access the Python framework through a pre-existing Python application?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't Terminal.app that's specifying the path.  It's the application.

The application calls the system function posix_spawn(), to which it is passing the pathname of the application to launch.

Even installing Python 2.x yourself, whether MacPorts or Homebrew or a downloadable installer from python.org, will most likely not work.  Those systems can't install things into /System.

You should look for a more up-to-date version of this app.